# function literals in scala for expression

Tags: scala

Hi I am new to scala and have a question.

When I specify the non abbreviated version of a funtion literal in a for loop, scala does nothing with it.

e.g.

```
    val myList = List("one","two","tree","four","five")
    //compiles but does not print anything
   for (arg <- lst) (arg:String) => {println(arg)}

    //does print one, two, tree, four,five on separated lines
   lst.foreach((arg:String) => {println(arg)})
```

On the other hand the abbreviated version of the above function literal ( println(arg) ) in a for loop does seem to work as expected:

```
    val myList = List("one","two","tree","four","five")
    //does print one, two, tree, four,five on separated lines
    for (arg <- lst) println(arg)
```

Is this a bug or did I misunderstand something?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug in Scala. When you specify the function, like this:

```
for (arg <- lst) (arg:String) => {println(arg)}
```

then Scala is indeed not doing anything with it, because you only specified the function - you didn't tell Scala to actually call the function. Your `for` loop basically means: "for each element in `lst`, declare this function".

You'll have to specify that you want the function to be called:

```
for (arg <- lst) ((arg:String) => {println(arg)})(arg)
```

This reads as: "for each element in `lst`, declare this function and call it with `arg`".

Note the difference with `foreach`:

```
lst.foreach((arg:String) => {println(arg)})
```

This means: "call `foreach` on `lst`, and pass it this function" - `foreach` is then going to call the function for each element in `lst`.

Comment: Keep in mind though that `((arg:String) => {println(arg)})(arg)` is a huge waste of everything, while `println(arg)` does the same and is more readable.

Comment: This was ofcourse just to show how the language works. Writing `lst.foreach(println)` does the same thing and is much more readable and efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jesper for this clear answer. I agree that ((arg:String) => {println(arg)})(arg) is a waste, but tried it to learn the language basic principles :-)

Comment: Definitely not more efficient than the imperative approach, since foreach uses a function object that requires an anonymous class as well as construction overhead.

Answer (score 1):

More of a side note, consider this

```
val a = for (arg <- lst) (arg:String) => {println(arg)}
a: Unit = ()
```

where `a` of type `Unit` does nothing, and

```
val b = for (arg <- lst) yield (arg:String) => {println(arg)}
b: List[String => Unit] = List(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>, <function1>, <function1>)
```

where we tell the for comprehension to deliver a collection of functions from `String` onto `Unit` (due to the `println`). Then we can apply each entry in `lst` to each corresponding function in `b` for instance like this,

```
(lst zip b).foreach { case (s, f) => f(s) }
one
two
tree
four
five
```

Note that `f(s)` is a shorthand for `f.apply(s)`.